# Recover "ps" command

Tags: package-management

I found myself in a situation where I need to reinstall the `ps` binary. I accidentally copied the binary to another location and immediately deleted it. The binary is no longer in the `bin` directory.

I have attempted to reinstall the `coreutils` package in Ubuntu, but `ps` was not reinstalled; is there another package where `ps` comes from?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Using `dpkg -S /bin/ps` will tell you that this program is in the `procps` package. Reinstall it using `apt-get install --reinstall procps`.

Answer (score 5):

**Using the Packages website**

The http://packages.ubuntu.com/ site comes in handy in such situations.

Example: [search package contents for ps](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=ps&mode=exactfilename&suite=precise&arch=any) reveals the `procps` package.

**Using the command-not-found feature**

Type the command misspelled and search the suggested packages:

```
$ ps-
No command 'ps-' found, did you mean:
 Command 'psi' from package 'psi' (universe)
 Command 'psc' from package 'sc' (universe)
 Command 'psf' from package 'tcm' (universe)
 Command 'ps' from package 'procps' (main)
```